# Android - Show numeric keyboard without an EditText

Tags: java, android

For my Android app I need to show numeric keyboard when the user clicks on an image, but without showing an EditText.
I want to then be notified when the user pressed a specific key, so that I can handle UI appropiately.

How could it be done?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =  (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(imageview_reference.getApplicationWindowToken(),     InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you! But what about a listener for a key pressed event?

Comment: I would use a `TextWatcher` to monitor. Let me see what else there is. Can you give us a better usecase. Is the number static? is it dynamic

Comment: Yes, that's working perfectly, but if the device has a hardware keyboard, the keyboard doesn't appear

Comment: Check out `Soft Input View` here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html